# Should I retain, autorelease or do nothing when returning NSArray of executeFetchRequest: result?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, retain, autorelease

Please have a look at the code below:

```
- (NSArray *)requestEntities:(NSString *)entityName {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity]; 

    NSError *requestError = nil;

    NSArray *result = [_context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];

    [fetchRequest release], fetchRequest = nil;

    return result;
}
```

and I need to use the result somewhere else, in this method, is result correctly returned(without retain or autorelease)? Also, what should its callers do when getting the result, retain it or use it straight away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that you're not responsible for objects returned by methods other than those containing `new`, `alloc`, or `copy`. The array you're given is almost certainly already autoreleased, so it will be released when your code finishes and it goes back to the run loop. If you need to hold onto the array beyond that point (e.g., if you want to keep those results around and refer to them to respond to future UI events) then you should retain the array, preferably by assigning it to a retained property.

I heavily recommend you read the [memory management programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) in full, or at least the first few sections which get right to the meat of what you're asking about.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, @zem, but when you say, "...when your code finishes and it goes back to the run loop," you are referring to the current method finishing.  I.e., if you want to retain the `autoreleased` array you should do so before the end of that particular method.

Comment: @chris No, as the guide I linked points out, you can return the object to its immediate calling method without any problem. You can generally follow your code flow and figure out when the end of your method is going to exit your code and return to the system; for example, if your method was called from `touchesBegan` or whatever, then eventually it will reach the end of touchesBegan and after that anything that is autoreleased is unlikely to stick around for the next UI response.

Comment: Or if your code is in drawRect or a display link callback or something lower-level, you can easily figure out when you're relinquishing control to the system until it decides to give your code another run. Most cocoa apps aren't scripts; your code isn't run straight from beginning to end; it is called by the system in response to timing or UI events. It is between these calls that the default autorelease pool is drained.